# Make the children element of a parent that has onClick immune

Tags: reactjs

So I have a product wrapper that I want to be clicked and on click redirect the user to the specific page of that product. And inside that is the button that can add the product to the cart, but the problem occurs here, because the wrapper has onCLick, when I click the button, the parent onClick is called, So I don't know how to make the button immune to the onCLick of the div.

```
<div onClick={() => navigate(product.id)}>
  <button onClick={() => add(product.id)>Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `onClick` event of a child is called, the event propagates by default and calls the `onClick` of the parent.

To avoid that, you should call `event.stopPropagation()` inside the child function.

```
<button onClick={(event)=>{event.stopPropagation(); /* rest of your code */}}>
```

Comment: Can i use this event on div?, because It doesn't work

Comment: No you use it inside button since it's the child, and that will stop the div onClick to be called. Make sure you added (event) as an argument.

Comment: Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_event_stoppropagation